# probability function for unfair dice

Tags: r

Given a fair four-sided die and let X denote the associated random variable. What is the probability distribution of X? What is the expectation of X?

- Use the  `sample` -function  to roll the four-sided die 20 times.
- Assume that the die is not fair: P(X=1)=0.5, P(X=2)=P(X=3)=P(X=4)=1/6.
- Use the  `prob`-argument to roll the unfair dice 20 times and provide summary statistics.

#1

```
x <- 1:4 
sample_function <- sample (1:4, size=20,replace = TRUE, prob = NULL) 
sample_function <- sum(sample (1:4, size=20,replace = TRUE, prob = NULL))
```

#2

```
my.sample <- function(die1=1:4,  prob1=NULL,Nsample=20) {
      die <- sample(die1, prob=prob1, replace = TRUE, size = Nsample)
      return(die)
    }
my.sample()
    
my.sample(die1 = 1:4, prob1 = c(1/2 , 1/6,1/6, 1/6), Nsample = 20)
```

I do not understand how can I calculate the probability distribution of `x` and how can I use prob function for unfair dice.

Comment: `summary(my.sample(die1 = 1:4, prob1 = c(1/2 , 1/6,1/6, 1/6), Nsample = 20))`

Comment: It might be instructive to increase `Nsample` drastically.

Comment: how is this a good idea if the question specifically asks about n=20 ? maybe use `replicate` instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Roland mentioned, your `Nsample` should be sufficient large (otherwise the Monte Carlo simulation result would be rather biased). If you wants the empirical probability distribution, you can use `prop.table` + `table` like below

```
s <- prop.table(table(my.sample(die1 = 1:4, prob1 = c(1/2, 1/6,1/6, 1/6), Nsample = 1e8)))
```

which gives

```
> s

        1         2         3         4
0.4999951 0.1666763 0.1666949 0.1666338
```

Comment: @Trusky Then OP can try `s <- prop.table(table(replicate(1e6, my.sample(die1 = 1:4, prob1 = c(1/2, 1/6,1/6, 1/6), Nsample = 20))))`

Comment: That looks better !